# Map Country Name with Currency ISO Code

Tags: apex, metadata-api

Using the 'CurrencyType' object and the getDescribe method on the User's CountryCode, I can fetch from Salesforce, the Currency ISO codes and Country Names separately, but not together. I am not able to find anything common between Country Names and Currency ISO codes to do mapping in Salesforce Apex. Is there any way to do this?

## Currency ISO Codes

```
List<CurrencyType> currencyList = [Select IsoCode from CurrencyType];
```

## Country Names

```
  Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = User.Countrycode.getDescribe();
  List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();
  for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple){
    System.debug('Country Name=>'+f.getLabel());
  }
```

Comment: You'll probably have to build your own mapping table in Custom Metadata.

Comment: Yes. Already reached this soltion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create a custom mapping of Countries and Currencies in Custom Metadata Types. No other solution than this but it worked perfectly.